# How to show sorted list in form

Tags: python, django

This works but don't know how to show on my page

```
sorted(glob.glob('*'+dvcs.hostname+'*'), key=os.path.getmtime)
```

I don't know what should I do. Here is my code

```
class Recentbackups(View):

    @staticmethod
    def get(request, pk):
        dvcs = Device.objects.filter(pk=pk)
        form = DeviceForm()
        context = {'dvcs': dvcs, 'form': form}
        return render(request, 'Recentbackups.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

at the moment youre just sending the objects `dvcs` and `form` to the `Recentbackups.html` as a Dictionary. Now you need to use it.

In the `Recentbackups.html`:
You can now access the variables via `{{dvcs}}` or `{{form}}` directly in the `Recentbackups.html`.

I don´t know what exactly is the content of the variables, but you can for example loop over them (if they are a list) and print then something for each object.
example:

```
{%for obj in form%}
<div>{obj}</div>
{%endfor%}
```

hope that helps in generell :D